# How to handle the dynamic URL path request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am a new to jmeter but am aware with the basics to correlate and parameterize values and run scripts for multiple users.
But i am stuck on an issue of correlating the dynamic values [found here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/how-to-handle-the-dynamic-url-path-and-process-the-request-in-jmeter)

This link was helpful in a way but i was not able to correlate the contents.

[image]

Any insights would do, Thanks in advance

Comment: show what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

These `152153667366` and friends seem utterly like [Unix Timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (time in milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970).

It means you don't need to "correlate" them, you need to "generate" them, check out JMeter's [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which returns current time in form of a Unix Timestamp

Just amend your HTTP Request Path to end with `?t=${__time(,)}` and that would be it.

Demo:

[image: JMeter TimeStamp Time Function]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Thanks your answer certainly is of great help, but I would also like to know the correlation of the values in the URL as "/562/azo2kbsx/xhr?t=" This keeps on changing for different cases ,TIA.